# ImageSource.FromFile not working in Xamarin UWP?

Tags: xamarin.forms, imagesource

I am using the [ImageSource.FromFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.imagesource.fromfile?view=xamarin-forms) to set the image source but the image not loaded in Xamarin uwp. Please refer to my code.

```
newImage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("C:/Users/Username/Desktop/Image1.png");
```

Thanks,
Santhiya A

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you could not pass file path to `FromFile` method. And the available parameter is the name of a file where in the uwp client project root path.

[image]

```
MyImage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("test.PNG");
```

For more please refer [working with image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin).