# How to convert the ImageSource.FromFile to stream in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

I want to convert Image to stream from the ImageSource.FromFile.

My Code:

```
   string location = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "data", "Demo.jpg");
   image.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(location);
```

The image is shown properly but I want to convert this image to Stream in Forms.UWP.
I tried the  **await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync()** this code to get the stream of the image from the location but it throws an exception.

Please suggest me how to convert the image from the file to stream in UWP?

- Santhiya A

Comment: "throws an exception" is not helpful.  What is the exact exception being thrown, and show us the code that causes the exception to be thrown

Answer (score 0):

This path `Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "data", "Demo.jpg");` is app's local path within UWP platform. And it is not app installation path. if place the  `Demo.jpg` in your project folder, you will not find it with above path. And the parameter of `ImageSource.FromFile(string file)` is file name, but not the complete path. For the detail please refer this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52363308/7254781).

> I tried the await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync() this code to get the stream of the image from the location but it throws an exception.

For UWP platform, you could use the following to converter the image file(build property is Content) to steam. For more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

```
private async Task<Stream> GetStreamAsync()
{
    var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Demo.jpg"));
    var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
    return stream.AsStream();
}
```

And if you want use above in Xamarin Forms client project, you need package above method with [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction).